# UWP convert resource override to style

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have button with custom color:

```
<Button>
<Button.Resources>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
</Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

I would like to move this to style, so I can just set Styles on my buttons instead of putting them in button xaml. The only way I have found is to override button template, which is ridiculous amount of XAML to change one color. There is no easy way to do this?

Comment: Please not that I am after internal resource defined in control template like `ButtonBackgroundPointerOver`, and not property on control which can be set with style like `Background`.

Answer (score 0):

> UWP convert resource override to style

`ButtonBackgroundPointerOver` solid color brush that used to set button pointer over status color, but it is not a button property, so we could not set it like setting button background property, if you want to effect the specific button, the better way is create custom button like this case [replay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819174/7254781) , and if you want to effect this to whole button on the page, you could define it in the page resource

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForeground" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackground" Color="#212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundPointerOver" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="#424242"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundPressed" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPressed" Color="#070707"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Except I do not want custom buttons, just visuals. I find it very crude to define custom template or class just to change style of some buttons - I thought there is better way to do it.

Comment: You could change `ButtonBackgroundPointerOver` by editing button style, but you need to edit the button's template, because `ButtonBackgroundPointerOver` was stored in the [`VisualState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj709909(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#default-style)

Comment: But that's terrible solution - editing button template to edit just one color. In my app I have several buttons, with different background/foreground/border colors, and to change them I need to copy button template 3 times. This looks like terrible design.

Comment: so, I think add  `ButtonBackgroundPointerOver ` into Button.Resources is easy to edit the button appearance.

Comment: Yes, but I have to do it for each button in application. Then if I want to for instance change another color I need to find all of these buttons, instead of changing style.

Comment: Please try to custom button and add the dependence property for `ButtonForegroundPointerOver`